# Subqueries turning up the same results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, distinct

Trying to right a piece that categorizes average movie ratings of different genres, grouped by number of kids in a family subscribed to the movie streaming plan.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.numbkids "Number of Kids",
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating),2) FROM netflix.ratings100 r
            JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid
            JOIN netflix.customers c ON c.custid = r.custid
            WHERE g.genrecode LIKE 'ACT') "Average Action Rating",
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating),2) FROM netflix.ratings100 r
            JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid
            JOIN netflix.customers c ON c.custid = r.custid
            WHERE g.genrecode LIKE 'ADV') "Average Adventure Rating",
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating),2) FROM netflix.ratings100 r
            JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid
            JOIN netflix.customers c ON c.custid = r.custid
            WHERE g.genrecode LIKE 'COM') "Average Comedy Rating",
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating),2) FROM netflix.ratings100 r
            JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid
            JOIN netflix.customers c ON c.custid = r.custid
            WHERE g.genrecode LIKE 'MYS') "Average Mystery Rating"
FROM netflix.customers c JOIN netflix.ratings100 r
   ON c.custid = r.custid
JOIN netflix.movies_genres g
   ON r.movieid = g.movieid
WHERE c.numbkids BETWEEN 1 AND 3
ORDER BY c.numbkids
```

The problem I keep getting is that the average rating shown is the same for families with 1, 2, and 3 kids.  I think it is just giving me the overall average, and ignoring the fact that I'm trying to get it to partition by number of kids.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking to do (you are missing the group by aggregation in your query):

```
SELECT c.numbkids, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'ACT' THEN r.rating END),2) as Average_Action_Rating,
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'ADV' THEN r.rating END),2) as Average_Adventure_Rating,
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'COM' THEN r.rating END),2) as Average_Comedy_Rating,
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'MYS' THEN r.rating END),2) as Average_Mystery_Rating

FROM netflix.ratings100 r
JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid
JOIN netflix.customers c ON c.custid = r.custid

WHERE c.numbkids BETWEEN 1 AND 3

GROUP BY c.numbkids
ORDER BY c.numbkids;
```

This should give you a 3 rows x 5 columns structure
-Columns being numbkids + 4 average ratings for genres
-Rows corresponding to 1, 2 and 3 kids

**EDIT:**
Alternately, below query will give you a numbkids x genre level data:

```
SELECT c.numbkids, g.genrecode, ROUND(AVG(r.rating),2) as Average_Rating

FROM netflix.ratings100 r
JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid AND g.genrecode IN ('ACT','ADV','COM','MYS') 
JOIN netflix.customers c ON c.custid = r.custid

WHERE c.numbkids BETWEEN 1 AND 3

GROUP BY c.numbkids, g.genrecode
ORDER BY c.numbkids, g.genrecode;
```

Answer (score 1):

The subqueries are not limited on the number of kids and also there is no join between the sub query and main query.

You dont need that many sub-selects. They make your query perform slow. See if this works!

```
SELECT c.numbkids "Number of Kids",
      ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'ACT' THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END), 2) AS "Average Action Rating",
      ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'ADV' THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END), 2) AS "Average Adventure Rating",
      ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'COM' THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END), 2) AS "Average Comedy Rating",
      ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN g.genrecode LIKE 'MYS' THEN r.rating ELSE 0 END), 2) AS "Average Mystery Rating"
FROM netflix.customers c JOIN netflix.ratings100 r
   ON c.custid = r.custid
JOIN netflix.movies_genres g
   ON r.movieid = g.movieid
WHERE c.numbkids BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY c.numbkids
ORDER BY c.numbkids;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subqueries are not taking the number of kids into account, so would return the same values, however subqueries shouldn't be necessary.
Something like the following should work, (not tested as I don't have the necessary tables/data set up)

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.numbkids "Number of Kids",
    ROUND(AVG(case g.genrecode when 'ACT' then r.rating else null end),2) "Average Action Rating",
    ROUND(AVG(case g.genrecode when 'ADV' then r.rating else null end),2) "Average Adventure Rating",
    ROUND(AVG(case g.genrecode when 'COM' then r.rating else null end),2) "Average Comedy Rating",
    ROUND(AVG(case g.genrecode when 'MYS' then r.rating else null end),2) "Average Mystery Rating"
FROM netflix.customers c
JOIN netflix.ratings100 r ON c.custid = r.custid
JOIN netflix.movies_genres g ON r.movieid = g.movieid
WHERE c.numbkids BETWEEN 1 AND 3
ORDER BY c.numbkids
```